# How to change the text of Close Button ToolTip from "Close" to others for MFC dialog - C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override tooltip text for Titlebar buttons (Close, Maximize, Minimize, Help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548987/override-tooltip-text-for-titlebar-buttons-close-maximize-minimize-help)

In the Windows form we have three buttons on the top right corner like min,max,close.

By default the close button has the tooltip as "Close". I need to change this text to be "Hide".

It seems not easy. Could you help me please?

Comment: Not really an answer but I hate it when the [x] button becomes hide like you won't let people shut down your application. Perhaps I have finished using your application and don't want it to remain running, which is why I am hitting the [x] button?

Comment: Yes, I also hate this kind of change. But it's the reqirement from customers. So, please give me some advices about how to implement it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Override tooltip text for Titlebar buttons (Close, Maximize, Minimize, Help. This document is for C#. I need to implement this requirement using c++. So, could you give me some technical suggestion or specific sample codes?