# C# Winforms Devexpress has other button tooltips?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, tooltip

In normal Winforms I have a maximize button with standard tooltips on mouse move.
Within devexpress my maximized button show after maximized "Restore Down" and in german "Wieder nach unten". It is bad, because not like the windows standard. I cannot change the tooltip, because I don´t know how to access the maximize button of the form.

Language: C#, Winforms
WIth UI Lib: Devexpress

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override tooltip text for Titlebar buttons (Close, Maximize, Minimize, Help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548987/override-tooltip-text-for-titlebar-buttons-close-maximize-minimize-help)

Comment: no it does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Localizer class that inherits from DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer. Override the GetLocalizedString method and return what value you'd like for the minimize/maximize buttons. For instance:

```
public class MyRibbonLocalizer : DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer
{
    public override string Language
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
        }
    }

    public override string GetLocalizedString(BarString id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case BarString.MinimizeButton:
                return "My Minimize string";

            case BarString.MaximizeButton:
                return "My Maximize string";

            default:
                return base.GetLocalizedString(id);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to register this localizer class in your RibbonForm in order for it to work. I typically do this within the constructor:

```
DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer.Active = new MyRibbonLocalizer();
```